# Radio buttons on WP admin page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm building a plugin that changes the site's background color in accordance with the user's choice, for practice. I'm doing it with radio buttons.
I want the user to have only one choice, like a normal radio button behavior, but in the admin page he can chose several colors like a checkbox behavior, and not even able to undo chose that was made.

The code:

```
<div class = "wrap">
    <h3>Please choose a color</h3>
    <form style = "line-height:400%" method = "POST" action = "">
        Black <input type="radio" name = "black" value = "Black" /> 
        White <input type = "radio" name = "white" value = "White" />
        Red <input type = "radio" name = "eed" value = "Red" />
        Green <input type = "radio" name = "green" value = "Green" />
        Yellow <input type = "radio" name = "yellow" value = "Yellow" /> <br/>
        Orange <input type = "radio" name = "orange " value = "Orange " />
        Blue <input type = "radio" name = "blue" value = "Blue" />
        Pink <input type = "radio" name = "pink" value = "Pink" />
        Purple <input type = "radio" name = "purple" value = "Purple" />
        Brown <input type = "radio" name = "brown" value = "Brown" /><br/>
        <p>Hax color<input type = "text" name = "hax" size = "5" /></p>

    </form>
</div>
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Use same name for all radio buttons

Comment: Please start to search for the HTML reference of your choice. You can start with reading books or learning about high quality online resources. Asking your way through *after* you've start without first thinkging about which tags are used for what and how they work is not really a good idea. Especially as the questions that will make you asking that will be largely off-topic on Stackoverflow. So first make a plan, then write the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that you did not link all the radio buttons into a single group. That way the radio buttons "know" that when you select one of them, all the others will unselect. You just need to give them all the same `name` attribute. This attribute is actually the name of the group they're on. 
You can see an example here:

http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="action" method="POST">
<div align="center"><br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Butter" checked> Butter<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Cheese"> Cheese
<hr>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Water"> Water<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Beer"> Beer<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Wine" checked> Wine<br>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The name tells which group of radio buttons the field belongs to. When you select one button, all other buttons in the same group are unselected. So use same name for all the radio buttons.

Just like,

```
        Black <input type="radio" name = "color" value = "Black" /> // here I use color as the name for all buttons
        White <input type = "radio" name = "color" value = "White" />
        Red <input type = "radio" name = "color" value = "Red" />
        Green <input type = "radio" name = "color" value = "Green" />
        Yellow <input type = "radio" name = "color" value = "Yellow" /> <br/>
        Orange <input type = "radio" name = "color" value = "Orange " />
        Blue <input type = "radio" name = "color" value = "Blue" />
        Pink <input type = "radio" name = "color" value = "Pink" />
        Purple <input type = "radio" name = "color" value = "Purple" />
        Brown <input type = "radio" name = "color" value = "Brown" /><br/>
```